# Как получить доступ к полям класса, который в свою очередь является полем шаблонного класса?

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++

В данном случае параметром шаблона функции является класс матрица, в arr находится сама матрица. Необходимо инициализировать arr (сделать обычную матрицу нужных мне размеров), а для этого необходимо знать размеры arr у передаваемых в функцию параметров m1 и m2. Как получить к ним доступ и возможно ли это?

```
template <class T>
TMatrix<T> operator*(const TMatrix<T> &m1, const TMatrix<T> &m2) {
   if (!m1.checkMul(m2)) throw "Умножение невозможно!";

   TMatrix<T> tempMul(m1.row, m2.col);
   for (int i = 0; i < tempMul.row; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < tempMul.col; j++) {
           for (int k = 0; k < m1.col; k++) {
               tempMul.arr[i * tempMul.col + j] += m1.arr[i * m1.col + k] * m2.arr[k * m2.col + j]; // arr не инициализирован, имеет размеры 0 на 0 по умолчанию, соответственно не может выполнить сложение
           }
       }
   }

   return tempMul;
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понял. Вы же уже сами осуществляете доступ к размерам ваших матриц: `m1.row`, `m2.col` и т.п. Размер `arr`, судя по коду, это просто произведение соответствующего `row` на соответствующий `col`. В чем тогда проблема? Причем здесь вообще "поля класса, который в свою очередь является полем шаблонного класса"?

Comment: доступ должен быть не к шаблонной матрице, а к обычной, которая хранится в m1.arr и.т.д. В объекте m1 размером 1 на 1 может находиться матрица 3 на 3, вот и нужно получить доступ к этой матрице 3 на 3

Comment: Ну так и доступайтесь себе на здоровье к `m1.arr`. Что вы уже и делаете. Только кто вам сказал, что это "класс" и что у него есть какие-то "поля"? Я бы предположил, что `arr` - это голый указатель на обычный голый одномерный массив. И с чего это вдруг "в объекте m1 размером 1 на 1 может находиться матрица 3 на 3"? Почему? Зачем? Откуда?

Comment: Matrix m1(2, 2);
 TMatrix<Matrix> tm1(1, 1, m1);
А каким образом и можно ли вообще получить информацию (кол-во строк, столбцов) в самом m1.arr?

Comment: Я не знаю, что делают ваши конструкторы и телепатическим возможностями  не обладаю. Поэтому мне не ясно, что я должен увидеть в этом вашем примере. Однако еще раз: я бы предположил, что `arr` - это голый указатель на обычный голый одномерный массив. Никаким образом никакой информации ни о каких "строках и столбцах" из него получить невозможно. Нет в нем никаких "строк и столбцов".